# Where IN multiple column in mysql from php array

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

Can't find how to do this query if clouse IN more than one column
I have example:

```
$post = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
$phoneNumbers = implode(",", $post->phones);
$emails = implode(",", $post->emails);

$sql = "SELECT phone_number,email,id FROM users WHERE phone_number,email IN (($phoneNumbers),($emails))";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Paramenters gets from post response, and I need to compare this with logical OR.
This example don't worked for me, result is nothing.
How I can do that. Thx

Comment: It looks like you are attempting a multi-column `IN ()`. Are the `phone,email`received by JSON to be interpreted as _pairs_ of values equivalent to `WHERE (phone = 'phone1' AND email = 'email1') OR (phone = 'phone2' AND email = 'email2')...`?

Comment: PHP's mysql_ API was deprecated a long, long time ago.

Comment: @Strawberry Good catch.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski need OR, sorry Im update question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$post = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
$phoneNumbers = $post->phones;
$emails = $post->emails;

$ors = [];
foreach ($phoneNumbers as $i => $number) {
    $ors[] = "(phone_number = :phoneNumber{$i})";
    $params[":phoneNumber{$i}"] = $number;
}

foreach ($emails as $i => $email) {
    $ors[] = "(email = :email{$i})";
    $params[":email{$i}"] = $email;
}

$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT phone_number, email, id FROM users WHERE ".implode(' OR ', $ors));
print_r($query);
$query->execute($params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Join two `WHERE IN` with `AND`:

```
SELECT phone_number, email, id FROM users WHERE phone_number IN ({$phoneNumbers}) AND email IN ($emails)
```

---

If you need to match phone number AND email, than generate your query:

```
$ors = [];

foreach ($phoneNumbers as $i => $number) {
    $ors[] = "(phone_number = :phoneNumber{$i} AND email = :email{$i})";
    $params[":phoneNumber{$i}"] = $number;
    $params[":email{$i}"] = $emails[$i];
}

$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT phone_number, email, id FROM users WHERE ".implode(' OR ', $ors));
$query->execute($params);
```

Comment: ...Unless the phone and email are to be interpreted as a pair in the same row....

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Updated query

Comment: Im sorry, Im updated answer, need logical OR instead AND

Comment: @dev.nikolaz If `match email OR password` than use first example

Comment: @Justinas this logic can be used without PDO with old syntax ? Because server side is very old, and need to rewrite more code. Or need find time to refactor old statements

Comment: @dev.nikolaz Yes, you can, just `mysql_` does not have prepared statements, so second example will not work, have to manually escape params.

Comment: @Justinas, Im is quickly accepted answer, but this is not right. This will work if email and phones arrays is have same length, each phone have email. But I answer another things. I have one table and I need to fetch rows where match email or phone number. Thx

Comment: @dev.nikolaz So use `OR` instead of `AND`: `WHERE phone_number IN ({$phoneNumbers}) OR email IN ($emails)`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  phone_number,
  email,
  id 
FROM users 
WHERE phone_number IN ($phoneNumbers)
  OR email IN ($emails)
```

Comment: what do you mean by *don't work* any errors? not expected result?